# Error: passing 'const SunscreenSPF' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers issue

Tags: c++, class

I am calculating how long one person can get sunburn with screen protection. As I like to use different approach to do things, I created a class called SunscreenSPF.

```
class SunscreenSPF
{
private:
    string skinColor;
    int SPF;
    int time;

public:
    SunscreenSPF(string skinColor, int SPF, int time)
    {
        this->skinColor=skinColor;
        this->SPF=SPF;
        this->time=time;
    }

    int calculateTime ()
    {
        return SPF*time;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const SunscreenSPF &data)
    {
        os<<"Skin Color = "<<data.skinColor<<endl
          <<"Time outdoors = "<<data.time<<endl
          <<"SPF Level = "<<data.SPF<<endl
          <<"Time to get sunburn with protection = "<<data.calculateTime()<<endl;
    }
};
```

I get this error: passing 'const SunscreenSPF' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]|

How can I fix this?

Comment: You need to return `os` from the `operator<<` function, else you'll encounter a warning.

Answer (score 1):

In the function `friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const SunscreenSPF &data)`, `data` has a `const` qualifier to it. But when `calculateTime()` is invoked, this member method doesn't provide the guarantee of not modifying the `data` object. Add a `const` qualifier to your `calculateTime()` function as

```
int calculateTime () const
{
    return SPF*time;
}
```